# Ruby Case class check

Tags: ruby, class, case

How can I get the following code to work (I want to decide upon an action based on the class of the arg):

```
def div arg
  material = case arg.class
             when String
               [arg, arg.size]
             when Fixnum
               arg
             end
  material
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison in the case statement is done with the `===` - also called the case equality operator. For classes like `String` or `Fixnum` it is defined as testing if the object is an instance of that class. Therefore instead of a class just pass the instance to the comparison by removing the `.class` method call:

```
def div arg
  material = case arg
             when String
              [arg, arg.size]
             when Fixnum
              arg
             end
  material
end
```

Additional note: In your example, you assign the result of the case block to a local variable `material` which you return right after the block. This is unnecessary and you can return the result of the block immediately, which makes the method a bit shorter:

```
def div(arg)
  case arg
  when String
    [arg, arg.size]
  when Fixnum
    arg
  end
end
```

Comment: I suggest you provide an explanation.

Comment: Sehr schön! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd prefer:

```
def div(arg)
  return arg if arg.is_a? Fixnum
  [arg, arg.size] if arg.is_a? String
end
```

Comment: With this version you may get an NoMethodError-exception (e.g. with `div(1.1)`.