# If statement and Case statement - Not matching

Tags: ruby

### Why would the `if` statement work, but the `case` statement not work?

```
class A
end      # => nil

a= A.new  # => #<A:0x00007fd9d6134770>
```

#### `If` statement works

```
a.class == A  # => true
```

#### `Case` statement does not work

```
case a.class   # => A
when A
  puts "done"
else
  puts "else"  # => nil
end            # => nil

# >> else
```

I read that case statement use `===` operators instead of `==`, how do I use `==` for the case statement?

Comment: Try the if statement with case equality `a.class === A`.

Comment: Trying to do the reverse, a case statement with ==

Comment: You can't use `==`, it is always `===`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby Case class check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957892/ruby-case-class-check)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form `case specific when archetype...` will always use the `archetype.===(specific)` subsumption check. To use `==`, you would need to be explicit, and use the other form: `case when boolean`:

```
case
when a.class == A
  puts "done"
else
  puts "else"
end
```

However, in this specific case (checking if an object belongs in a class), if you don't care whether `a` is an instance of `A` or an instance of a subclass of `A` (which is almost always the case), you can still use the subsumption check, like this:

```
case a         # Note: not a.class
when A
  puts "done"
else
  puts "else"
end
```

because `A === a` when `A` is a class is pretty much the same as `a.is_a?(A)`. Note that this is different from `a.class == A`, which will not be true if `a` is an instance of a subclass of `A`. For example for `class Dog < Animal`, and `fido = Dog.new`, both `fido.instance_of?(Animal)` and `fido.class == Animal` are false, but both `fido.is_a?(Animal)` and `Animal === fido` are true.)